# Sinch Service does not seem to start with Android Studio and Parse.com (Android Messaging Tutorial)

Tags: android, service, android-studio, instant-messaging, sinch

I am following this tutorial: https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-messaging-tutorial-using-sinch-and-parse

Github for tutorial: https://github.com/sinch/android-messaging-tutorial

The issue I have is that the service does not seem to start at all. I have gone over the code and cannot spot anything that looks wrong (but then again i'm a beginner lol).

I am not receiving any broadcast back in the MenuFragment3 class and due to that the progressDialog just keeps spinning. I have also checked to see if a service is running on both a number of emulators and a real device, like I said it seems as though the service never starts and I really cannot see why.

If you need anything more let me know and thanks for any help!

Firstly I start the service when a user logs in here:

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageService.class);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Heres the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.yupo.dominic.yupo" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".UserAuth"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/title_login_area">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StudentLogged"
        android:label="@string/title_student_area">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Register"
        android:label="@string/register">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LectureLogged"
        android:label="@string/title_lecture_area">
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".MessageService">

    </service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Heres the MessageService class:

```
package com.yupo.dominic.yupo;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.ClientRegistration;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.Sinch;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.SinchClient;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.SinchClientListener;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.SinchError;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.messaging.MessageClient;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.messaging.MessageClientListener;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.messaging.WritableMessage;

public class MessageService extends Service implements SinchClientListener {

private static final String APP_KEY = "mykeyiscorrect";
private static final String APP_SECRET = "mysecretiscorrect";
private static final String ENVIRONMENT = "sandbox.sinch.com";
private final MessageServiceInterface serviceInterface = new MessageServiceInterface();
private SinchClient sinchClient = null;
private MessageClient messageClient = null;
private String currentUserId;
private LocalBroadcastManager broadcaster;
private Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("com.yupo.dominic.yupo.StudentLogged");

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Parse.initialize(this, "thisiscorrect", "thisiscorrect");

    currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();

    if (currentUserId != null && !isSinchClientStarted()) {
        startSinchClient(currentUserId);
    }

    broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void startSinchClient(String username) {
    sinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(this).userId(username).applicationKey(APP_KEY)
            .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET).environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();

    sinchClient.addSinchClientListener(this);

    sinchClient.setSupportMessaging(true);
    sinchClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true);

    sinchClient.checkManifest();
    sinchClient.start();
}

private boolean isSinchClientStarted() {
    return sinchClient != null && sinchClient.isStarted();
}

@Override
public void onClientFailed(SinchClient client, SinchError error) {
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("success", false);
    broadcaster.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

    sinchClient = null;
}

@Override
public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("success", true);
    broadcaster.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

    client.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
    messageClient = client.getMessageClient();
}

@Override
public void onClientStopped(SinchClient client) {
    sinchClient = null;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return serviceInterface;
}

@Override
public void onLogMessage(int level, String area, String message) {
}

@Override
public void onRegistrationCredentialsRequired(SinchClient client, ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
}

public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
    if (messageClient != null) {
        WritableMessage message = new WritableMessage(recipientUserId, textBody);
        messageClient.send(message);
    }
}

public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
    if (messageClient != null) {
        messageClient.addMessageClientListener(listener);
    }
}

public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
    if (messageClient != null) {
        messageClient.removeMessageClientListener(listener);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    sinchClient.stopListeningOnActiveConnection();
    sinchClient.terminate();
}

public class MessageServiceInterface extends Binder {
    public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
        MessageService.this.sendMessage(recipientUserId, textBody);
    }

    public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        MessageService.this.addMessageClientListener(listener);
    }

    public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        MessageService.this.removeMessageClientListener(listener);
    }

    public boolean isSinchClientStarted() {
        return MessageService.this.isSinchClientStarted();
    }
}
}
```

Here my version of the ListUsersActivity from the tutorial (For me it is called MenuFragment3 which is part of a sliding menu which is called from the StudentLogged or LectureLogged activities)

```
package com.yupo.dominic.yupo;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MenuFragment3 extends Fragment{

View rootview;
ArrayList<String> names;
ParseUser currentUser;
String currentUserId;
ListView usersListView;
ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
BroadcastReceiver receiver;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    if(currentUser.getString("type").equalsIgnoreCase("Lecturer"))
    {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu3_2_layout, container, false);
    }
    else
    {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu3_layout, container, false);
    }

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    progressDialog.show();

    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "broadcast received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Boolean success = intent.getBooleanExtra("success", false);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            //show a toast message if the Sinch
            //service failed to start
            if (!success) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Messaging service failed to start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("com.yupo.dominic.yupo.StudentLogged"));


    currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", currentUserId);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {
                    names.add(userList.get(i).getUsername().toString());
                }
                usersListView = (ListView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
                namesArrayAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                                R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);
                usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                        openConversation(names, i);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Error loading user list",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    return rootview;
}

public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("username", names.get(pos));
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(List<ParseUser> user, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                //Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MessagingActivity.class);
                //intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                //startActivity(intent);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "working",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Error finding that user",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: If you used my answer below, could you please mark it as accepted? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to initialize Parse using your Sinch key and secret. In addition, you should initialize Parse in your application's onCreate method. Try:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();

    if (currentUserId != null && !isSinchClientStarted()) {
        startSinchClient(currentUserId);
    }

    broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```